# SCSI 3 Persistent Reservation when working with MPIO

Tags: storage, scsi, san

We have 2 windows servers running on windows server 2012R2
we have a shared disk and a witness disk to implement a quorum behavior in the shared disk arbitration. 
both quorum and data are currently configured with Fiber channel MPIO.
we do not provide the hardware so our customers work with various SAN vendors.

We are using the SCSI3 persistent reservation mechanism to make the disk arbitration, we are reserving the quorum witness disk from one machine and checking it from the other (passive) machine.

As part of the reservation flow each machine registers its unique SCSI registration key and uses it to perform the reservation when needed.

The issue occurs when MPIO is configured since in our current implementation (so it seems ) the key is registered on the device using the io path which is currently used to access the storage.

Once there is a failover/switch in IO path the reservation fails due to the fact that the key is not registered for that path.

Is there a way on the device/code level to have a SCSI reservation key be registered on all IO paths instead of just the specific path the registration command arrived on?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this question belongs on https://serverfault.com/ as it isn't related to programming.

Comment: thanks i will try posting it there as well. it is just that we use C++ code to create the SCSI related operations so in a way it is also a programming question

Comment: Check if your storage system supports SCSI3 commands and if there are any features of working with SCSI3 reservations. Also you should put reservation on the LUN itself but not on the path to it.

Comment: Hi, how do i put the reservation on the LUN and not the path? how does translate in the command itself?

Answer (score 0):

pr type need to be set as "Exclusive Access - Registrants Only". And all paths on active windows host must be registered for pr.
https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100016085.html
and https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100018257.html  may help.